# Subclassing Rails FormBuilder for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formbuilder

I have a custom FormBuilder that overwrite the value of a text_field.

```
class TimesheetFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def text_field(method, opts)
    #Get a reference to the model object
    object = @template.instance_variable_get("@#{@object_name}")

    value = object.send(method)
    (opts ||= {}).merge!(value: value + '(foo)')
    super(method, opts)
  end
end
```

I have a nested form. A timesheet has many worklogs

```
<%= form_for @timesheet, :builder => TimesheetFormBuilder do |timesheet_form| %>
  <%= timesheet_form.fields_for :worklogs do |worklog_form| %>
    <%= worklog_form.text_field :monday %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to call the method on the object.

When I get the object

```
object = @template.instance_variable_get("@#{@object_name}")
```

Then I get an error

**`@timesheet[worklogs_attributes][0]' is not allowed as an instance variable name**

There is a way to parse the `object_name` so I get `@timesheet` and `worklogs` and `0` so I can do

```
@timesheet.worklogs[0]
```

But is there a better way?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `@object` which is the Worklog instance

`@object.send(method)` is the value of the text field

Comment: Do you mean this:    object = @template.instance_variable_get(@object_name)    ?    Please show your final code lines so I can see. I am have the same exact error message, but I don't understand your answer here.

Comment: So, it seems like we do not need this line at all: 

object = @template.instance_variable_get("@#{@object_name}") 

Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly you don't need it anymore

Comment: Just a question, where did you put the file timesheet_form_builder.rb? under `lib/timesheet_form_builder/` folder? or `lib/action_view/helpers/form_builder/`...? thanks